# Openness of the metric space $X = [0, 1] \cup \{2\}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ with metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, then in this topology space, is the set $[0, 1]$ open? I think it is open, since $(0, 1)$ is open, and as for $0$ and $1$, can find two open ball $B_{0.5}(0), B_{0.5}(1)$ inside $[0, 1]$, then $[0, 1]$ is open.

Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, $[0,1]$ is open in $X$. Interestingly, it is also closed

Comment: In fact, $[0, 1]$ is an open ball in $X$; it is (for example) the ball of radius 1 centered at 0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $[0,1]$ is open because its complement, $\{2\}$ is closed.